# Why can't I see the copy-constructor being called in the case of returning an object from a function in c++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, local-variables

In the following code ret variable is stack variable, and once foo returns the memory allocated to ret no longer exists. But string is a class, and a copy constructor is called to copy the contents of ret to var. I wanted to test the validity of this using a test code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){ test(); }
    A(const A &){ std::cout << "copy constructor A" <<std::endl; }
    virtual void test(){ std::cout<< "A" <<std::endl;}
    A & operator=(const A &); 
};

A & A::operator=(const A &)
{
    std::cout << "assignment operator A" << std::endl; 
}

A functionA(int a)
{
    A localA;
    return localA;
}

int main()
{
     A a = functionA(2);    
}
```

what I expected the output to be was:

```
  A 
  copy constructor A
```

however the following code outputs the following:

```
  A
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Copies may be elided. There are hundreds of duplicate posts on this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization.

In a sentence, the compiler sees that you will just be copying the value of `localA` to `a` (in `main`), and rather than running a copy operation, it performs an optimization where it just directly writes to `a` in the function `functionA`.